# How to crack or break Obfuscation using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have seen some websites, which displays the first page source for rest of the pages. For example if we visit xxxx.com's fist page and look at its page source and if we visit xxxx.com's second page web contents are different we see the 2nd page web content in the tools like fire bug, but when we look 2nd page page source then in 2nd page source we have 1st page source only. This is called Obfuscation. My Question is, Is there is any technique or mechanism to see the 2nd page source only. If it is there how it is possible. Can we do or adopt same technique to our site also? if it is how?

Am new to web domain. Please help me.

Comment: is `xxxx.com` like `foo.com` or is the site you want to understand?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation I suppose that *could* fall into the realm of Obfuscation

Comment: Ya its like foo.com only

Comment: javascript can be obfuscated, but I think you mean something like http redirection. post an example site you want.

Comment: When I visit some foo.com website i observed that 2nd, 3rd etc page source are same as the first page, but contents what they are displaying is different not same as first page only and in the fire bug also i can see different contents. My question is how see 2nd, 3rd etc web page contents in the page source. Is it possible . Is there any techniques to do this and how.

Comment: Does the second "page" have a different URL or is it the same URL as the first page with the content loaded dynamically via AJAX?

Comment: Urls are different for each page, not dynamically loaded using ajax.

Comment: @webspider26 for example in `latin.fm` you do not see the html code for the stations because it is generated in javascript. is this what you mean, you want to check the javascript generating the markup?

Comment: Please tell me How to check javascript generating markup.

Comment: This is not obfuscation. This is just HTML+Javacript+AJAX.

Comment: @selbie If it is just HTML+javascript+AJAX then in the page source of different "pages" i am getting first "page" page source only. Please tell me and how to view respective "page" page sources only. Please tell me

Comment: @webspider26 -  The source HTML of a page doesn't ever change.  But the DOM content in the page can change as a result of the page's use of Javascript. Javascript can download more scripts, content and/or modify the page's DOM, and change HTML elements. None of this actually changes the page's source. But it does change the DOM. The tool you really want is a DOM inspection tool - which is likely already installed for you. On Internet Explorer: Press F12. On Firefox - download Firebug, then press F12. On Chrome, press CTRL+SHIFT+I.

Comment: @webspider26 - All of these tools will allow you inspect the DOM as it is currently displayed in the page - and you can convert the DOM back to raw HTML simply by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Start Firebug `F12`
- select `Net`
- select `JS`
- click `any js file`

[image]

then you can find obfuscated js, or minified js.  If it is minified use a tool like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: I followed this approach, but i look at the headers and i didn't find any obfuscated js or minified js. I found one javascript file called dtm_fm.js.

Comment: The headers do not show info about the minification or obfuscation, you have to see the js code to determine if it has been minified, obfuscated or nicely indented js.